# Are Spring SpEL queries safe from SQL injection attacks?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Are the `"#{variable}"` Spring Expression Language SpEL values safe from SQL injection attacks? For example:

```
@Mapper
public interface UrlInfoMapper {
    public static final String SELECT_BY_ID = "select * from url WHERE ID=#{ID}";
    public static final String DELETE_BY_ID = "DELETE FROM url WHERE ID=#{ID}";

    @Select(SELECT_BY_ID)
    UrlInfo getFromUrlById(String ID);

    @Update(DELETE_BY_ID)
    void delete(@Param("ID")String ID);
```

I checked the reference but can find no mention of the values substituted being escaped for SQL characters like quotes.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.17.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions

I could find no mention on the web about SpEL and SQL injection (only JPA which this project isn't using).

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=spel+sql+injection&ia=qa

This papers discusses vulnerability with SpEL in the view, but not the database.

https://www.mindedsecurity.com/fileshare/ExpressionLanguageInjection.pdf

Spring Core 2.6.1, Spring Boot 1.5.6, Spring Expression 4.3.10.

Comment: I discovered this is using a library called [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/).

Comment: Data access technologies using `PreparedStatement`s are safe from SQL injection. In any case, it should be easy to verify this by creating a simple app and trying a few attack vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they are.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MockTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Test
    public void sqlInjections() throws Exception {
        User user = userMapper.getUser("admin'--");
        assertNull(user);
    }


@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    @Select("select * from user WHERE name =#{name}")
    @Results(value = {
             @Result(property = "name", column = "name"),
             @Result(property = "password", column = "password"),
             @Result(property = "encrypted", column = "encrypted"),
             @Result(property = "permission", column = "permission")
           })
    User getUser(@Param("name")String name);
```

And

```
mvn test

Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```